# What is Apple's policy on buying and reviewing your own app?

Tags: iphone, app-store

What is Apple's policy on buying and reviewing your own app? Do they allow it, or discourage it, or is it in the fine print of dev agreement that I shouldn't do that?

I know that for Android apps you can't purchase your own app, they actually prevent the purchase from completing.

Comment: If it feels shady, its probably disallowed.

Comment: Just one single purchase I'm talking about, just to get it off on the right foot. Not talking about paying others to do it or any kind of bulk operation. Please don't judge me here. I'm asking purposely because I'm aware that it may not be viewed as good practice, and would like to know if Apple has actually commented on this or put something in their guidelines for it.

Comment: Why not take $2 out of your pocket, and put $1.40 back in?

Comment: G, If I would find out that a developer has purposely reviewed their own app I would never buy anything from that developer ever. Buying it yourself in order to see that it actually works is another matter, but that is not my point. Reviewing your own app is moot - it is not really a review at all is it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple store policies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy your own app, that's not a problem, You can even review your own app. But why would you want to do either?

Comment: ... ehh... someone doing that would probably do that in order to give their app a high rating?

Comment: This is true, but why not leave that up to actual users?

Comment: Because it's not good enough to rate highly on its own merits?

Comment: Well, either way, if you want true, honest ratings, leave it to the unbiased users who legitimately purchased the app. In my opinion, it looks bad on the developer for rating his/her own app.

Comment: Unless your app is very expensive, why would you not buy it? It's the only way to validate that the end-to-end purchase experience (other then watching over someone else's shoulder while they buy it). As far as rating goes, you should rate your own app. Would you run for office but refuse to vote for yourself? Writing an anonymous review is over the line, but rating your own app is definitely kosher.

Comment: iOS Developing and Politics are completely unrelated. Theres no way to know who purchased the app, unless they 1.) leave a rating, 2.) email you, or 3.) tell you personally. Buying your own app doesn't make sense, seeing as how its probably on your device anyway from developing it. Apple, I'm pretty sure validates purchase just fine.

Comment: The basic point is to get a good launch of the app. I'm talking here about a single purchase and review, not mass purchasing or paying others to do it (which is commonly done by the way). One single purchase and positive review to get the thing off to a good start.

Comment: You are better off with a strong marketing plan.

Comment: Your "one good review" will lead to many lost sales if real reviews in any way conflict.  Customers are not dumb, they can spot this kind of thing a mile away.

Comment: I agree with Kendall, you would essentially be creating a false, biased representation of your app.

Comment: I buy my own apps as a QA double check (Did I upload the correct build to iTunes Connect?), and to test the user experience (Does the app install from iTunes?  Does the upgrade process corrupt previous data due to some weird bug?)  It also gives me a non-expiring version, unlike dev builds.  Paying Apple 30% is a small cost.

Comment: There are many checks Apple goes through before they mark an app live. I have personally never heard of a corrupt update. Also, in order to submit an app to iTunes Connect, you have to set your app as "Ready for Upload" in iTunes Connect, then you have to verify what certificate you used to sign said app, so I dont see how you can "upload the incorrect app". Buying your own app is understandable, as hotpaw2 made a valid argument.

Comment: But as for reviewing your app, it may be viewed as unethical to some users. So it's really up to the developer whether they want to do either. I havent been able to find anything in the documentation that is against either.

Comment: @WrightsCS : There are many checks that Apple does NOT do before they mark an app live.  I've bought more than 1 app from the iTunes App store that crashed on first launch.  So I do a QA buy to make sure my app isn't one of them.  I also see nothing unethical about a review as long as you don't hide your identity (and thus potential bias).

Answer (score 6):

Who cares what the Apple policy is.  It is unethical.

Furthermore, if you do this and it conflicts with many other reviews your astroturfing will stick out like a sore thumb and people will grow to distrust you.  Once lost, it's incredibly hard to regain a customers trust - do not treat it so lightly.

Comment: +1 for "Who cares what the Apple policy is. It is unethical."

Comment: Thanks for the judgement. I'm a bit suprised at these responses though. If I was unethical I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. If I was unethical I'd pay people to buy the app and write reviews. I don't do that and never have and never will.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply you were unethical, and sorry for the strong response - it's just that it really rubs people the wrong way, and they get REALLY mad when they see an obviously faked review for something that burned them.  That carried over into responses to your question including my own.

Comment: It's only unethical if you hide or obfuscate your identity and/or post false or misleading information.

Comment: Then it's just silly.  If you say plainly in your review "I am the app author" then sure it's not unethical any longer.  But what are you going to say you didn't already say in the application description?  And when a customer sees your five-star rating but does not have a five-star experience, he's going to think you are a jerk.  There is zero upside in leaving a review for yourself, at best nothing bad will happen and at worst you anger a lot of people.

Comment: What if your app has a lot of 1 star reviews (but a high average rating), and they are all issues that have been fixed, or misunderstandings by users, or minor peeves such as "your app didn't have feature x, so I'm leaving it a 1 star review"? The problem is that iOS users seem to be pretty bad about leaving reviews. It tends to be users who have problems who review apps.

Comment: If that is common then do star ratings really matter?  Or is it the case that some apps are better at getting users to leave comments if they are having a good experience.  That's what I would focus on now, find some way to implore happy users to leave a review...

Comment: I dont think this is a very good answer. This answer does not give any reasons WHY it is unethical.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a few positive ratings can mean the difference between attracting organic growth and fizzling out.  From my experience with various app developers, I have seen no evidence that Apple manages self-ratings, so you can go ahead and do it technically without disclosure.  However there is a risk of violating the trust of your customers, and likely very little reward.

My recommendation, to steer clear of the ethical black area, is to ask your network of contacts to rate your app: friends, family, previous co-workers, etc.   Tell them you worked really hard on it, and ask them to download the app, and write a genuine review / rating based on what they think.   There's obviously some bias in your favor, assuming they like you as a person, but I wouldn't consider it unethical unless you're asking them to lie.

Answer (score 1):

Some developers do that in order to be on top of the chart.

For example, you can look at MacPhun LLC on the apple store, product name Color Splash, introduced Sept 21st 2011 at 10pm ET, Sept 22nd 2011 at 10am ET, the product has 60 5 stars user review.  It is now among the top 15 best sellers overall.  Might be a 70$ investment, that they will make back in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you'd purchase your own app. It's the only real way to check that installation and updates work. But don't review it, I think that would be unethical.